# pytorch asynchronous calculation did not seems to work

Tags: asynchronous, pytorch

First, I make some large model

```
class LargefcNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, dropout=0.2):
        super(LargefcNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.end = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.dropout(self.relu(self.fc1(x)))
        x = self.dropout(self.relu(self.fc2(x)))
        x = self.dropout(self.relu(self.fc3(x)))
        x = self.dropout(self.relu(self.fc4(x)))
        x = self.dropout(self.relu(self.fc5(x)))
        x = self.dropout(self.relu(self.fc6(x)))
        x = self.end(x)
        return x
```

And make models and inputs into each gpu device

```
model1 = LargefcNet(100, 10000, 100, dropout=0.4).to(tc.device('cuda:0'))
model2 = LargefcNet(100, 10000, 100, dropout=0.4).to(tc.device('cuda:1'))
model3 = LargefcNet(100, 10000, 100, dropout=0.4).to(tc.device('cuda:2'))
input1 = tc.randn(100, 100).to(tc.device('cuda:0'))
input2 = tc.randn(100, 100).to(tc.device('cuda:1'))
input3 = tc.randn(100, 100).to(tc.device('cuda:2'))
```

```
# this one is for gpu loading
output1 = model1(input1)
output2 = model2(input2)
output3 = model3(input3)


start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    output1 = model1(input1)
print(f'output1: {time.time() - start_time}')

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    output2 = model2(input2)
print(f'output2: {time.time() - start_time}')

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    output3 = model3(input3)
print(f'output3: {time.time() - start_time}')

#method 1
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    model1(input1)
    model2(input2)
    model3(input3)
print(f'output1, output2, output3: {time.time() - start_time}')

#method 2
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    model1(input1).to(tc.device('cuda:0'))
    model2(input2).to(tc.device('cuda:1'))
    model3(input3).to(tc.device('cuda:2'))
print(f'output1, output2, output3 with to: {time.time() - start_time}')

#method 3
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    outputs = [model(input) for model, input in zip([model1, model2, model3], [input1, input2, input3])]
print(f'outputs: {time.time() - start_time}')
```

But the results are below

```
output1: 0.13068866729736328
output2: 0.13286447525024414
output3: 0.13341188430786133
output1, output2, output3: 0.37032580375671387
output1, output2, output3 with to: 0.366225004196167
outputs: 0.36612439155578613
```

why my code did not work in device by device? it looks like it runs in sequentially not parallelly.

I expect method 1, 2 results in 0.13~0.2 seconds to calculation and method 3 is what I'm trying to calculate.

Comment: I saw some data and I think this code work in parallely, accodring to nvidia-smi, those models and inputs work parallelly but each calculation speed drop down 1/3 each by each. I don't know why...

Comment: Why would it run in parallel, your code is running sequentially whatever the number of distinct devices you decide to use.

Comment: OMG you are right. Thank you for your comment. I never thought that my code can in incorrect

Answer (score 0):

What I'm trying to looking for is

```html
for i in range(10):
    outputs = tc.nn.parallel.parallel_apply([model1, model2, model3], [input1, input2, input3])
```

this code.